# Jax-rs with Jersey : different Json stream. Why ?

Tags: json, jax-rs

I have two test machines, one (lets call it workstation **A**) with java 1.6 and Netbeans 7.2, the other (workstation **B**) with java 1.7 and Netbeans 7.3. I check the Jersey libraries and release numbers are different.
I created a simple web service using netbeans wizard "Restful webservices from database" on workstation **A** and it produces a json like this:

```
{"someName":[{"id":"2","nome":"1 Maggio"}, ..., {"id":"6","nome":"25 Dicembre"}]}
```

As you can see it is a Json Object with a single name value pair where the value is an array of objects.

Doing the same operations on workstation **B** I get:

```
[{"id":"2","nome":"1 Maggio"}, ..., {"id":"6","nome":"25 Dicembre"}]
```

This a simple json array, not a json object as with workstation **A**.
May be I inadvertently put something different in the web service configuration on the two machines, but I have no idea what to check.

I suspect the different result depends on the different version of jersey and java sdk. 
Can somebody confirm on this ?
I have to write the client for the web service so I need a consistent output.

Thanks
Filippo

Comment: Did you found the reason for the different behavior?